# Read Permissions on library site gets access denied with Limited access on site

Tags: document-library, permissions, library

I have a site with limited access for the group "ABCD" and the same group in library in the same site with Read permissions.

I added a user to group "ABCD" having Limited access on site and also to the Library in the same group "ABCD" with Read permissions.

When checked for users' permissions on the site it gives limited access but when checked in library it shows read permissions.

I don't want users to access the site, I only want users to access the library just to view the content of it.

Despite that, the user is unable to access the library.

My Question is:

1. Is the group "ABCD" with limited access overriding library group "ABCD" with Read permissions?
2. Should the group name be changed?
3. Should the user be removed from the group "ABCD" in library?

How can I enable users to access the library without accessing the site?

Answer (score 1):

The group at the site and at the library is the same group - you can't remove the user from a group at the library without also removing them from the group for the site. That group has the permission "Limited Access" to the site, and "Read" to the library.

"Limited Access" is SharePoint's way of granting people enough permission to the site to be able to see a library in it.

The scenario you describe is how it should be if you want a group to be able to read a library but not otherwise access the whole site.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse,I tried removing the user from the group in library and add individually outside the group,But I wonder why the user is still unable to access the library.. This scenario should work but unfortunately it is not!! Any suggestion how can we acheive this, Thanks again

Comment: Can you post screen shots of the results of Check Permissions on the site and the Library Permissions on for the library for the user account you trying to configure?

Answer (score 0):

You have to break the inheritance of library from site. No need to have either group or individual user in site containing "Limited Access" permission.
Now, give access to user in library through library setting> library permission to user as read permission.
Note the url of library, then hit the browser with that url logging with read permission user. It should work.